# Query TFS for items that changed to a certain status

Tags: team-foundation-server

Using TFS 2010, how do i query the items that changed TO a certain status on the last 7 days?

My goal is to see what bugs the developers fixed through last week.

Answer (score 2):

The following query returns all bugs that have been resolved on the last seven days:

```
[Work Item Type] = Bug
And [State] <> Open
And [State] <> New
And [Resolved Date] >= @Today - 7
```

The key to this is the *Resolved Date*. Its meaning is:

> The date and time when the work item was moved into a resolved or done
>   state.

For more information see the [TFS field reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997872.aspx).

Comment: How it would be to know how many were reopenend?